# jQuery Ajax Race Condition?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have the below JavaScript code that iterates through a list of textfields on a page.  It takes the text in the textfield as a price, sends it to the server via an AJAX GET, and gets the parsed double back from the server.  If any of the returned prices are less than an existing price, the form shouldn't submit.

The problem is that the form is submitting before all the AJAX requests are finished because of the non-blocking immediate response nature of the Ajax calls.  I need to set up a wait() function (or a callback when all the Ajax methods are complete) but don't know how to do that with jQuery.

Any suggestions?

```
// .submitForm is a simple button type="button", not type="submit"
$(".submitForm").click(function(e){
   var submittable = validatePrices();
   if (submittable) {
     $("#myForm").submit();
   }
});

function validatePrices() {
    var submittable = true; 

    $(".productPrice").each(function(){
        var $el = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/get_price.jsp", 
            async: false,
            dataType: "html",
            data: "price=" + $el.val(), 
            success: function(data)
            {                  
               var price = new Number(data.split("|")[1]);
               var minPrice = new Number($el.data("min-price")); 
               if (price < minPrice) 
               {
                  $el.addClass("error");
                  $(".dynamicMessage").show().addClass("error").append("<p>ERROR</p>");
                  submittable = false;
               }
            }
        });
        return submittable;
    });
}
```

Comment: Using a synchronous HTTP request back to your server for each separate field is going to make your site terribly slow.

Comment: Updated the post to clarify that .submitForm isn't a type="submit", just a type="button", so the e.preventDefault() isn't needed.

Comment: You should use `parseFloat` or `parseFixed` instead of `new Number` for a constructor.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss `parseFixed`?

Comment: You should google/search for jquery $.Deferred - looks like a perfect use for that.

Comment: @bluedevil2k your AJAX calls are not asynchronous because you're explicitly setting "async" to `false`.  If it's not an issue with the form submit happening due to the button, then you're going to need to debug it systematically.

Comment: @Ian - what I meant was parse to some fixed length since it appears to be currency - either by rounding or cliping if it is over 2 (or desired number) of decimal places...

Comment: is there a reason to use parseFloat instead of new Number()?

Comment: several reasons, for example: `var j = new Number("123.04"); alert(typeof j); var p = parseFloat("123.04"); alert(typeof p);` alerts "object" and "number", parseFloat also performs better (mostly) - search jsperf related stuff for that. Note that `var i = new Number("33")` creates an instance (typeof object) whereas `var n = Number(33")` creates a primative type (typeof number) whereas parseFloat only produces "number" type for valid values. You can search here on this site and in search engines for more, and it is somewhat "opinion" except for that little "new" part which is a constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already using synchronous AJAX (a really bad idea for your user experience), so that's not the problem. The problem is that you need to cancel the default action in the "submit" handler:

```
$(".submitForm").click(function(e){
   var submittable = validatePrices();
   e.preventDefault(); // this line
   if (submittable) {
     $("#myForm").submit();
   }
 });
```

Using a synchronous HTTP request back to your server for each separate field is going to make your site terribly slow. You're going to have to check the parameters at the server again when you submit the form anyway, so it'd be much better to just check then and return an error.

*edit* — now that the situation is clearer, I think that the way to proceed is to stop doing the AJAX validation checks completely.  Why?  Well, even if you perform those tests, you *still* need to make essentially the same validity tests when the form is actually submitted. You can't rely on the JavaScript validation code actually running, as in any other form validation scenario. If you're doing the validation at form submission time anyway, it'll save on a bunch of HTTP requests to just do it all at the same time.

Comment: Right, I changed it to async:false to get it to work, but I'm looking for the right Ajax async way.  The e.preventDefault() doesn't fix it because the button isn't a type="submit"

Comment: @bluedevil2k OK well that clears up the issue. As I wrote, I think that the real "right way" to do this is to simply do all the validation on the server. You have to do it in the form post handler (at the server) anyway, because you won't be able to be certain that the javascript tests have been done.

Comment: I'm leaning towards a hybrid solution now.  I do the validation of the prices on a blur() of the textFields and set a global submittable variable on that pass through (with async:true) on those.  If they press the "Save" button directly from the textfield, the Ajax call won't finish and it'll go to the server side validation.

Comment: @bluedevil2k yes that sounds like a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

You're not canceling the form submission.  You have to work strictly with the ajax callbacks (if you would like to use them asynchronously, which would be nice).

```
$(".submitForm").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   validatePrices().done(function () { /* ajax success function here */
       if (submittable) {
           $("#myform").trigger('submit');
       }
   }
});

function validatePrices() {
    var checks = [];

    $(".productPrice").each(function(){
        var $el = $(this);
        checks.push($.ajax({
            /* snip */
    });
    return $.when.apply(null, checks);

}
```

Comment: I think your answer is close, but the first function doesn't work because the submittable variable isn't created.  How do you pass the submittable variable from validatePrices() back to the click() function?

Comment: @bluedevil2k I was just using this as an example .. what you could do is store `submittable` (or some analog) and write to it during each individual ajax callback, then check it in the `$.when` done callback